# Maximo List View: Filter where field is null OR equals value?

Tags: filter, conditional-statements, where-clause, maximo, or-condition

I have a `division` field in *Work Orders* in Maximo 7.6.1.1.

I would like to filter the work orders in the List View `where division is null or division = 'FORESTRY'`.

[image]

Is it possible to do this in the List View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran a few tests on 7.6.0/Oracle 12 and it appears that it's not supported, both on WILDCARD and TEXT search types. It seems that you can only use the ~null~ operator alone although it's not specified in the *latest* documentation. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLKT6_7.6.1.1/com.ibm.mbs.doc/gp_ui/r_wildcard_operator_search.html

Your best bet is probably to use a saved query or to type it directly in the Where Clause Advanced search dialog.